# UWP XAML Intellisense DataTemplate.DataType

Tags: xaml, uwp, intellisense, datatemplate

Why does intellisense filter out interfaces and abstract classes?  If I set DataType to an abstract class, it seems to still work fine.  Perhaps this is just a bug?  Also, related, inside DataTemplate, when I try to `{x:Bind}` it filters out inherited properties, so if I have `Item : Base`, and `Base` has a property `Name`, and `DataType="Item"`, it filters out property `Name` and if I use it anyway, it seems to resolve to the class name.  Did I miss something in the docs?  Should I be making special non-abstract wrapping classes for every type I want to bind to xaml controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After my testing, it seems that inherited interface-properties are not recognized by the compiler when using the X:Bind. But it applies to abstract classes.

You could follow the sample to check your steps.

XAML code:

```
<ListView x:Name="List" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Fruits}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Fruit">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind price}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Code behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Fruit> Fruits{get;set;}
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Fruits = new ObservableCollection<Fruit>()
        {
            new Fruit(){name="apple",price=12},
            new Fruit(){name="peach",price=15},
            new Fruit(){name="pear",price=8},
            new Fruit(){name="banana",price=31},
            new Fruit(){name="grape",price=5}   
        };        
    }
}
public class Fruit: IFruit
{
    public string name { get; set;}
}
public abstract class IFruit
{    
    public int price { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I think you're right.  This is unfortunate when you need the `x:DataType` to be an interface or abstract class.  I was hoping there was a workaround that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: Derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension#remarks), when using {x:Bind} with data templates, you must indicate the type being bound to by setting an x:DataType value.
In my scenario, when I use x:DataType indicate child class, it doesn’t filter out the property of base class, such as ‘price’.